# Attach object using iOS6 UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios6, sharing

I'm migrating to use the UIActivityViewController for sharing in iOS6, but I can't figure out how to create email attachment objects to be included when sharing by email.

The corresponding code in iOS5 is:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"application/XXX" fileName:fileName];
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have very limited control over UIActivityViewController, but if you're attaching well-know mime types, I found you can get it to work correctly by providing the associated file extension in a file URL. For example, if your attachment is a vCard, use the ".vcf" extension in the file URL:

```
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
// The file extension is important so that some mime magic happens!
NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vcard.vcf"];
NSURL *fileUrl     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

[data writeToURL:fileUrl atomically:YES]; // save the file

// Now pass the file URL in the activity items array
UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:
    @[@"Here's an attached vCard", fileUrl] applicationActivities:nil];
[vc presentModalViewController:avc animated:YES];
```

Comment: This actually worked, thanks markiv :) I combined this with another guide on how to create custom files for an app (e.g. files using .myApp), and got that to work as well with the fileURL.

Comment: sorry for bringing up this old question, but shouldn't `[data writeToURL:filePath atomically:YES]` be `[data writeToURL:fileURL atomically:YES]`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yes or I believe [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES] would work as well.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wondering why their files aren't being shared using UIActivityViewController to apps like DropBox and other generic file handling applications, what you really want is a UIDocumentInteractionController.

Use it something like this:

```
class ViewController {
    var openInController:UIDocumentInteractionController!

    init() {
        openInController = UIDocumentInteractionController(URL: docURL)
    }

    func shareDoc {
        openInController.presentOptionsMenuFromRect(CGRectZero, inView: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you can't do this with the UIActivityViewController -- I can't even manage to make it present HTML content for the message body -- so you may be better off using SLComposeViewController.

Comment: It is possible to add html content by tagging the string you pass into activity items with <html><body>...</body></html> - only then will it be interpreted as html.

Comment: @SMSidat are you sure? that's exactly what I did and it was rendered literally (i.e. not interpreted as HTML)

Comment: I'm pretty sure - I've done it and it works.  I don't really want to hijack this Q&A thread, so if you have one on this already, I'll be happy to help you there, or you can make a new one with a copy of the relevant part of your code and I'll see what I can do