# How to share Animated gif

Tags: ios, objective-c, share, gif

This is my code for sharing gif but i'm not able to share animated gif, i,m getting only image.

```
NSData *animatedGif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]]; 
     NSArray *sharingItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: animatedGif, nil];

NSLog(@"%@", sharingItems);
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: What is the name of the file or value of `fileName` ?

Comment: filename is path of gif

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26623931/3308174